# Degenerate vs Degeneracy

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you distinguish between the verb and acting/being in the state of?

Does degeneratum capture that concept (I.E - propter degeneratum or per degeneratum)? Or does that instead translate as a person: “because of the” and “by the”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, degenerate is actually two different words pronounced differently by emphasis. One is the adjective pronounced de-GEN-erate and the other is the verb degene-RATE. Then there is the noun, de-GEN-eracy, as you have written.

In Latin, the adjective is *degener -is* and the verb *degenero -are*. So, we have for example:

***Degeneres animos timor arguit.*** (Fear is proof of the degenerate mind.)
Virgil, Aeneid, Book IV

The participle, degeneratum, used as a noun, is rarely found, although there is in Livy the sentence:

***[Tarquinius] ea arte aequasset superiores reges, ni degeneratum in aliis huic quoque decori offecisset.***
([Tarquin] would have equalled earlier kings in this skill, if his **degeneracy** in other things had not also impugned his honor in this respect.)

Charles Folsom commented about this, "Livy is fond of using the participle in the neuter gender substantively, in this way, when it denotes the *cause* of anything." Normally the participle will have adjectival force.

In modern Latin, the word degeneratio is sometimes used as the noun degeneracy. For example, the medical term degeneratis cordis (degeneration of the heart). In general, the word *corruptio* was much more common than *degeneratio*.